# CRM 2011 + Create User Form Disabled

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I want to add simply a User.

**1.** I go to the Administration-> Users -> clicked on 'New'. This opens a new form for the user but form is disbaled and showing a pop-up that you can create user from Office-365, please click here.

**2.** I clicked on a LookUp(User lookup) on a form, from there i clicked on 'New' button. It opens a new form for the user but did not show any link or something.

May i not create a User from CRM??
Do i need to go to Office 365 portal?? Is it mandatory??

Any kind of idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

In a CRM 2011 Online instance with Office 365 authentication you need to use the Microsoft Office 365 portal.

You can find a guide here:

http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/08/29/add-a-new-user-for-crm-2011-online-using-the-microsoft-online-services-portal/

Comment: So, from the CRM itself, you can not create user. I need to go to 365 portal to crate user. That is fine.

But does it mean that User form will be disabled in CRM??
Even we can not enter First Name or Last Name..??

Generally CRM allows you to enter First Name and Last Name then t will redirect you to 365 portal.

Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: The form is not disabled, only some fields are disabled. To change that fields (as First Name or Last Name) you need to use the portal (or AD if the Active Directory Synchronization is enabled)